# For three matrices $A, B$ and $C$ of the same order, if $A$=$B$, then $AC$=$BC$, but converse is not true.

Tags: matrices

> For three matrices $A, B$ and $C$ of the same order, if $A$=$B$, then $AC$=$BC$, but converse is not true.

I guess $A,B,C$ all are square matrices of the same order.
$$
A=B
$$
multiplying by $C$ from right side,
$$
\implies AC=BC
$$

But why is the second statement "converse is not true" ?

$AC=BC$, multiplying by $C^{-1}$ from the right
$$
ACC^{-1}=BCC^{-1}\implies AI=BI\implies A=B
$$
right ?

Comment: Not every matrix has an inverse.

Comment: Yes, and if $C = \mathbf 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

Consider:
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\0&2
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad B=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\0&3
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad C=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and note that $C$ is not invertible

Comment: alright. so does that mean that if $C$ is invertible the converse is true ?

Comment: Yes. If it is invertible your proof is correct

Comment: thanx. i think tht clears my doubt